# Export-Clixml creating binary file which cannot be read by less

Tags: powershell, vi, less-unix

I am writing a powershell script in which I am using

`Get-EventLog -logname System | Export-Clixml "syslogs.xml"`

to get System logs in xml format. Once I create that xml I have to move it to a Linux host.
I tried copying this xml file to linux host and then when I am doing `less syslogs.xml` I am getting a message that this might be a binary file, and less is showing non readable characters.

However, when I am doing `vi syslogs.xml`, I am able to view the xml.
Can anyone please tell me why `less` is detecting `syslogs.xml` as binary file and how can I fix it?

Thanks

Comment: As an aside, there's some really good tooling available on Linux for processing `Export-Clixml` output, and it can handle any encoding... It is, unsurprisingly, [PowerShell](https://github.com/PowerShell/PowerShell/blob/master/docs/installation/linux.md).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`Export-Clixml` defaults to UTF-16, which `less` doesn't grok. I'm surprised vi can (but I can confirm it does). Try `Export-Clixml -Encoding UTF8`. This still exports with a BOM, which `less` shows as two binary characters. If this bothers you, `-Encoding Default` will use the platform default encoding, which might be anything. Or you can use `recode` on the Linux side: `recode utf16.. syslogs.xml` will convert the file from UTF-16 to whatever the default character set for the system is. Again, this might be anything; to avoid lossage, you'll probably want to stick to at least UTF-8, which most tools can process. `recode utf16..utf8` will recode to UTF-8 without a BOM, which is probably the most compatible format on Linux.